# Get the first row from consecutive sequence of group

Tags: r

I want to get the first row in each group.

E.g. :- I have a data frame

```
df =>
id  col_1   col_2   col_3
1   var_1   11      ba
2   var_1   12      ba
3   var_1   13      sw
4   var_1   13      sw
5   var_1   14      ba
6   var_1   11      ba
7   var_1   2       ba
8   var_1   45      ba
9   var_2   11      ba
10  var_2   12      ba
11  var_2   13      sw
12  var_2   13      sw
13  var_2   14      ba
14  var_2   11      ba
15  var_2   2       ba
16  var_2   45      ba
17  var_3   11      ba

output would be =>
id  col_1   col_2   col_3
1   var_1   11      ba
3   var_1   13      sw
5   var_1   14      ba
9   var_2   11      ba
11  var_2   13      sw
13  var_2   14      ba
17  var_3   11      ba
```

If i use duplicate function then it give first row only by col_1.

Comment: with dplyr `df  %>% group_by(col1,col2,col3) %>% top_n(1)`

Comment: What constitutes a "group"? The triplet (`col_1`, `col_2`, `col_3`)? Or (`col_1`, `col_2`)? Or ...?

Comment: @R.Prost That doesn't seem to match OPs expected output.

Comment: @Maurits Evers It's an example, give me a dput and i'll tweek it, probably need some arrange first... point is you can use top_n().

Comment: dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:17, col_1 = c("var_1", "var_1", "var_1", 
"var_1", "var_1", "var_1", "var_1", "var_1", "var_2", "var_2", 
"var_2", "var_2", "var_2", "var_2", "var_2", "var_2", "var_3"
), col_2 = c(11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 45L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 45L, 11L), col_3 = c("ba", "ba", "sw", 
"sw", "ba", "ba", "ba", "ba", "ba", "ba", "sw", "sw", "ba", "ba", 
"ba", "ba", "ba")), .Names = c("id", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3"
), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: BTW, I assumed a new group will start whenever col_1 or col_3 does not match col_1 or col_3 in the previous row, or when col_2 does not equal lag(col_2, 1) + 1

Comment: @R.Prost The data is right there. No need for `dput`; just do `read.table(text = "...")`. Point is, it's *not* just a simple matter of `top_n()`.

Comment: @Maurits Evers thumb_up indead read.table. Looks like Len did a good job there

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%  
  group_by(col_1, col_2, col_3) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  filter(id == 1 | !(col_1 == lag(col_1, 1) & col_3 == lag(col_3, 1)))

     id col_1 col_2 col_3
  <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
1     1 var_1    11 ba   
2     3 var_1    13 sw   
3     5 var_1    14 ba   
4     9 var_2    11 ba   
5    11 var_2    13 sw   
6    13 var_2    14 ba   
7    17 var_3    11 ba
```